# Codeception: List all tests of a group

Tags: testing, command-line-interface, grouping, codeception

It is possible to execute one or several groups of tests in Codeception. There are multiple ways to assign a test to a group (tag with `@group` annotations, add a group configuration in a `yaml` or add a group `txt` file).

Is there a way to list all tests which are assigned to a specific group?

I tried `codecept dry-run`, but this does not accept the `group` parameter, and `codecept run` executes all tests (which I dont want).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in command in Codeception for that.

If you only specify groups via `@group` tags you can use `grep` to find the test files for a group. If you use [other ways to define groups](https://codeception.com/docs/4.x/AdvancedUsage#Groups) this method will not work.

For example to search for all tests files with the group `shop`:

```
grep -ro '@group shop' tests/
```

You may need to replace `tests/` with the path where your tests are located.

Similar command to list all groups:

```
grep -rho '@group.*' tests/ |sort |uniq
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, however this does cover only one of the multiple way to assign a test to a group. I dont know which way was used by other developers. Therefore the tool itself should gather the tests and return the list.

Comment: good point, I was not aware of other ways than specifying group via tags :) No effort involved as I needed this myself and I only use the `@group` annotation. Updated the answer to note the limitation.